Adding users to Spotify project programatically while in develop
I built a super lightweight app for some team building things we wanted to do internally at work. This isn't intended to be monetized just a little fun way of bonding.
Other then apply to make this a production app (takes months to do) does anyone have another way of adding users to the spotify dashboard programatically? The auth works and im fine with the 25 person limit, its just adding them to the project manually that I want to avoid
Thanks!
